# Send API Triggered MobilePush to mobile device using REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, mobilepush, marketingcloudapi, sfdcmobilesdk-android

I am trying to send a Push notification to a sample android application which I created from Android Studio for testing. I Added my application in FireBase Console and getting my Device Token from there.
In SFMC I've created an app with the token provided from Firebase and created an API triggered MobilePush.
But I am not sure what will be the proper use case to fire MobilePush from Marketing Cloud through API.
Can someone please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Sample might help you -- good luck!

```
import com.salesforce.marketingcloud.MarketingCloudSdk;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;

public class MobilePush {
  private MarketingCloudSdk marketingCloudSdk;
  private FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging;

  public MobilePush() {
    // Initialize the Marketing Cloud and Firebase libraries
    marketingCloudSdk = MarketingCloudSdk.getInstance();
    firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance();
  }

  public void sendMobilePush(String message) {
    // Set up the MobilePush payload with the desired message and other data
    MobilePushPayload mobilePushPayload = new MobilePushPayload.Builder()
      .setMessage(message)
      .build();

    // Send the MobilePush to the Android application using the Marketing Cloud and Firebase libraries
    marketingCloudSdk.getPushMessageManager().send(mobilePushPayload);
    firebaseMessaging.send(mobilePushPayload);
  }
}
```

You can then call the sendMobilePush method from your Android Studio project to send the MobilePush to the Android application.

Answer (score 0):

See documentation site for the API reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/postMessageContactSendPush.html